# Paypal Payment (Web) Pro-supported merchant countries

Tags: paypal

I want to use DirectPayment API but the merchant, my client, is outside America. Is Paypal Payment Pro(Web Pro)  or any international variant available in countries other than US UK and Canada?

This url says only 3 merchant countries are supported: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/

while this one says it can be set even if the merchant has Hong Kong address or maybe other foreign accounts:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business-Archive/Apply-paypal-advanced-pro-without-US-adress-telephone/td-p/486022

Can anyone please confirm the list of Merchant countries supported by Pro?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be eligible for Payments Pro, the PayPal account being used will need to be a US, UK, or Canadian account.  I know some people in other countries, though, who simply get an address at a UPS Store in the US, for example, and then open an online bank account with that address that is also in the US, and of course follow that trend for everything PayPal may request of you to activate the Pro account.

Essentially, you're giving your a business a US presence and would be operating out of the US, so you would need to figure out what tax implications (in US or your country) this may have and make sure to do everything correctly and legally, but I know people do it so it can be done.

Once you have a Pro account you can accept payments with credit cards from lots of different countries, so that may be where some of the confusion is coming from.  Again, though, Pro is indeed only available in the US, UK, or Canada.

Comment: @Andrew Angell:  PayPal Payments Pro is it still supported in above mentioned three countries or extended to some other countries too ?

Comment: The full Payments Pro feature-set is still only available in the countries mentioned above.  Braintree works in many more countries, though, and there are also some other "Pro Hosted" solutions that work in a few additional countries like Australia and some others.